# C# intermittent "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located"

Tags: c#, exchange-server

Longtime lurker, first time poster.

I've seen a lot of questions about impersonation via Exchange2010 (which is what I'm doing), but everything I've seen so far has to do with invalid code syntax or invalid passwords.  Hopefully someone can help me with my problem, which is a little more odd.  I'm just trying to make an e-mail, get the appointments from another calendar on the same domain, and send the e-mail with those appointments listed.

My code works, but occasionally it will give me the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
Additional information: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
```

I deliberately removed any error checking from the code and let it crash upon run.  If I try again immediately, it may or may not work.  If it try again in five minutes, same story.  About 75% of the time it works on the first run, and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (the error is pointing to the RedirectionUrlValidationCallback, which I've also tried to check to debug/test to no avail). I'm checking four different calendars, and this error can happen on any one of them at the same line.  I can't see what's wrong in my code, so it's really frustrating.

First I initialize stuff to prepare the e-mail to send:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

const int NUM_APPTS = 10;
ExchangeService serviceAuth = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
serviceAuth.Credentials = new WebCredentials("me@mydomain.com", "PASSHERE");
serviceAuth.AutodiscoverUrl("me@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

I make the email, etc, then I go check the calendar and try to see the entries:

```
ExchangeService serviceCALONE = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
serviceCALONE.Credentials = new WebCredentials("CALONE@mydomain.com", "PASSHERE");
serviceCALONE.AutodiscoverUrl("CALONE@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
CalendarFolder calendarCALONE = CalendarFolder.Bind(serviceCALONE, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
CalendarView cViewCALONE = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);
cViewCALONE.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointmentsCALONE = calendarCALONE.FindAppointments(cViewCALONE);
```

This is the RedirectionURLValidationCallback function that I used from elsewhere on MSDN:

```
private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = true;
    // This was changed to default to true because an error started appearing with:
    // "The autodiscover service could not be located"

    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see (other than the fact that I comment tons to myself as I learn), I tried to return true regardless.  It doesn't seem to change anything either way.

The error can either happen during the e-mail init or the calendar check, but both times iirc it's at the .AutodiscoverUrl line.  I'm running this off a test box hosted via Rackspace, if that matters.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Service.Credentials` in this format:

```
Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domainname);
```

Also, check if the password for the email address has expired.
If the password has expired you will get this error from Autodiscover.

Another troubleshooting option to test Autodiscover externally is to use [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyser](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/).

If all else fails I would recommend enabling [Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) to help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I've tried the service credentials formatted that way. It actually errors out for me.  I assume this has something to do with 2010 vs whatever one that's initially for (I saw it on another thread).  I've tried with user as user and as user@domain (even though I'm aware user@domain shouldn't work).

Like I said in the question, the password hasn't expired since it works sometimes and sometimes it immediately doesn't.  However, since I also read that on here I went and reset the password to all of the accounts in question about a week ago to no avail.

Comment: I will try the tracing method because I haven't tried it to see what it says yet.

Comment: Putting in the listener doesn't really tell me much. I  did it exactly the way the MSDN article said and its giving me the last successful EWS request.

The debug output:

A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
Additional information: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

This time the first time worked and second didn't.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the AutoDiscover and use the server url directly instead?
`service.Url = new Uri("https://yourserver/ews/exchange.asmx");`

Another thing to check is if you have a SSL certificate problem on your server (E.G. maybe an expired or invalid certificate). 

IIS logs could also provide you with some helpful information.

Comment: I will ask Rackspace to check their IIS logs.  

Since Rackspace uses that emailsrvr url for autodiscover, I don't really think trying to point at a static place will help me very much there either.

Since the e-mails work fine (and the program itself executes with and without that UrlCallback above defaulted to both true and false 65% of the time), I'm going to say that's also not the problem.

I do appreciate the help so far though.  All of these responses I've gotten are ones that (mostly) had occurred to me as well and didn't end up fixing anything.